# Сравнение первого элемента столбца (Series), состоящего из списков

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, анализ-данных

Имеется DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(score)
df['scores']=df['scores'].astype(str)

s = df.scores
res = s.str.extract(r'^\[(?P<full_score>\S+?)\s\((.+?)\)')
res = pd.concat([res[1].str.split(",", expand=True)], axis=1)

new_names = ['1st', '2st', '3st', '4st', 'OT']
new_scores.set_axis(new_names, axis="columns", inplace = True)
new_scores = new_scores.fillna('0:0')
new_scores = new_scores.astype(str)

def get_new_frame (s):
    return s.str.split(':')

new_frame = new_scores.apply(get_new_frame)

          1st       2st       3st       4st        OT
0    [30, 32]  [30, 26]  [31, 29]  [23, 27]  [27, 19]
1    [30, 29]  [28, 37]  [35, 32]  [25, 25]    [0, 0]
3      [0, 0]    [0, 0]    [0, 0]    [0, 0]    [0, 0]
4      [0, 0]  [29, 37]    [0, 0]  [45, 28]    [0, 0]
5      [0, 0]  [37, 34]    [0, 0]  [36, 37]    [0, 0]
..        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
352  [12, 27]   [24, 6]  [26, 15]  [26, 17]    [0, 0]
353  [18, 19]  [25, 20]  [27, 28]  [14, 15]    [0, 0]
354  [21, 17]  [17, 17]  [34, 19]  [22, 20]    [0, 0]
355  [14, 27]  [21, 16]  [16, 20]  [27, 17]    [0, 0]
356  [21, 20]  [24, 14]  [22, 24]  [22, 22]    [0, 0]
```

Не могу никак сообразить, как можно сравнивать значения из разных столбцов. Например, первое значение из первого столбца `['1st'][i][0]` с первым значением третьего столбца `['3st'][i][0]`.

Изменение типа данных, как я понял, для каждой ячейки `num = [int(x) for in s]`.
Но как сделать, чтобы `['1st]num[0]` можно было сравнивать со значениями из других столбцом, например `['3st']num[0]`?

Получить хочу новый dataframe с отсортированными данными, нужно задать условия сравнения целых однозначных и двузначных натуральных чисел из разных столбцов по нескольким параметрам: >, <, =, <=, >= и указать разницу значений из разных столбцов, как условия сравнения ((['1st'].str[0] - ['2st'].str[0]) > 15)

```
        1st       2st       3st       4st        OT
0  [30, 27]  [30, 26]  [31, 29]  [23, 27]  [27, 19]
1  [30, 29]  [28, 27]  [35, 32]  [25, 25]    [0, 0]
2   [15, 9]  [17, 18]  [23, 21]    [0, 0]    [0, 0]
3  [28, 12]  [27, 29]  [34, 29]  [45, 28]    [0, 0]
4  [22, 21]  [17, 24]  [25, 21]  [36, 37]    [0, 0]
5  [27, 12]   [24, 6]  [26, 15]  [26, 17]    [0, 0]
6  [23, 19]  [25, 20]  [27, 28]  [14, 15]    [0, 0]
7  [21, 17]  [17, 17]  [34, 19]  [22, 20]    [0, 0]
8  [31, 27]  [21, 16]  [18, 20]  [27, 17]    [0, 0]
9  [21, 20]  [24, 14]  [22, 24]  [22, 22]    [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на измененный вопрос:

> нужно задать условия сравнения целых однозначных и двузначных
>   натуральных чисел из разных столбцов по нескольким параметрам: >, <,
>   =, <=, >= и указать разницу значений из разных столбцов, как условия сравнения ((['1st'].str[0] - ['2st'].str[0]) > 15)
>
> Именно интересует математические операции над значениями из разных
>   столбцов, как условия для сортировки таблицы.

```
In [130]: d["1st"].str[0].astype(int) - d["2st"].str[0].astype(int)
Out[130]:
0     0
1     2
2     0
3   -29
4   -37
5   -12
6    -7
7     4
8    -7
9    -3
dtype: int32
```

**NOTE:** Pandas оптимизирован для работы с табличными данными - когда каждая ячейка таблицы представляет из себя скалярное значение. Если вы храните в ячейках сложные структуры (списки, кортежи, словари), то работать с такими фреймами вам будет очень неудобно и большинсво встроенных методов Pandas не будут правильно работать с такими данными. Преобразуйте ваши данные таким образом чтобы получилась плоская таблица или воспользуйтесь трехмерными структурами - например `numpy` или `xarray`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Все работает. Последний вопрос, как каждое значение в этом дата сете поменять на int, без применения в каждом условии метода .astype(int)?

Answer (score 2):

Исходный фрейм:

```
In [152]: d
Out[152]:
        1st       2st       3st       4st        OT
0  [30, 32]  [30, 26]  [31, 29]  [23, 27]  [27, 19]
1  [30, 29]  [28, 37]  [35, 32]  [25, 25]    [0, 0]
2    [0, 0]    [0, 0]    [0, 0]    [0, 0]    [0, 0]
3    [0, 0]  [29, 37]    [0, 0]  [45, 28]    [0, 0]
4    [0, 0]  [37, 34]    [0, 0]  [36, 37]    [0, 0]
5  [12, 27]   [24, 6]  [26, 15]  [26, 17]    [0, 0]
6  [18, 19]  [25, 20]  [27, 28]  [14, 15]    [0, 0]
7  [21, 17]  [17, 17]  [34, 19]  [22, 20]    [0, 0]
8  [14, 27]  [21, 16]  [16, 20]  [27, 17]    [0, 0]
9  [21, 20]  [24, 14]  [22, 24]  [22, 22]    [0, 0]
```

решение:

```
In [153]: d["1st"].str[0] == d["3st"].str[0]
Out[153]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

---

**пояснения:**

извлекаем первые элементы списков из столбца `1st`:

```
In [154]: d["1st"].str[0]
Out[154]:
0    30
1    30
2     0
3     0
4     0
5    12
6    18
7    21
8    14
9    21
Name: 1st, dtype: object
```

извлекаем вторые элементы списков из столбца `1st`:

```
In [155]: d["1st"].str[1]
Out[155]:
0    32
1    29
2     0
3     0
4     0
5    27
6    19
7    17
8    27
9    20
Name: 1st, dtype: object
```

Comment: Имел ввиду, не логическое сравнение, если взять [‘1st’][0], то оно [30, 32], [‘3st’][0], [30, 29]. И надо сравнить 30 и 30, 32 и 29( первые и вторые значения, это например). То есть первые значения в первом столбце и первые значения в третьем( втором или четвёртом)

Comment: @baDAattitude, я именно так и сравнивал методами Pandas. Какой результат сравнения вы хотите получить? Можете привести в вопросе датасет, который вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: При сравнении данными методами, данные имеют тип int?

Comment: @baDAattitude, при сравнении данными методами данные имеют тот тип, который у вас в списках.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как данными методами реализовать новый фрейм, как описано в условии.

Comment: @baDAattitude, подскажу когда увижу в вопросе что именно вы хотите получить. Но только не словами, а в виде датасета ;)

Comment: добавил в описание, подобный датасет)

Comment: @baDAattitude, `в первом столбце все первые значения > вторых, вторые значения второго столбца < первых значений третьего столбца и тд.` - что значит `"и тд."`?

Comment: То есть, условий может быть неограниченное количество и абсолютно разные. Например значение ['2st'].str[0] больше или меньше в 2 раза значения ['3st0.str[0]. И когда вашим способом сравнивал значения, у меня получается такая путаница (9 > 14, 6 > 21, 26 < 9)

Comment: Именно интересует математические операции над значениями из разных столбцов, как условия для сортировки таблицы. Спасибо, что помогаете.

Comment: @baDAattitude, см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131590/211923)